Why is potential directly proportional to charge?
In my textbook, it’s written that conductors' charge is directly proportional to voltage and they used this idea to develop the concept of capacitance. How can you prove this for any conductor?

It's assumed as a consequence of experimental results, starting with Coulomb's experiments.

John has answered your question. Look up Coulomb's law

See, for example, Section 1.11 of Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (3rd Edition).

I think the generic answer to that would be the same as in classical mechanics. It's "by definition". There is a bit of a subtlety here because "voltage" is the potential difference between any two points, which you have to be careful with. A capacitor with two plates can carry an additional "monopole" charge which be non-zero even if you "discharge" the potential difference between the two plates with a short. One can do this for any number of conductors. They can be internally on the same potential, even if the whole network is net charged.

From Gauss's law, the electric field is related to the charge distribution in a region by an integration operation.
And by definition, the potential is related to the electric field by another integration operation.
Integration is a linear operation, therefore scaling the charge distribution in an electrostatic system by some factor $A$, will scale the electric fields in the system by $A$, and therefore scale the potentials in the system by $A$.

Can you show me the mathematics please
